# In Python, how do you make a loop?

Tags: python

I have started learning Python and was wondering how to make a loop, I cant find a website that has it so if you knew it would be great!

Comment: Man, you're gonna get a lot of hate for this question! My suggestion: read a book or Google: "Python tutorial"

Comment: Why so many down-votes??????? :(

Comment: SO many down votes because this is off-topic. You don't have a problem which you need help solving, just ask for something which you can google for in 2 minutes.

Comment: Its not so much off topic, however it is something that Google or py docs could easily answer. One of the reasons a question is downvoted is if it does not show research. Questions are meant for specific problems you are having a hard time solving, not for broad issues that documentation can cover. I know documentation can be difficult, but this question will seem lazy to many people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways.

```
while True:
```

That loops until you put `break` on a line.

The two Aleksander Lidtke mentioned.

```
for x in range(10): #Loops through the following code 10 times
```

And:

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
for items in x: #the variable items is assigned to 
                #each variable as it iterates through
```

To learn more about python, read [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/144933072X) book.

Comment: You could just use a condition in the `while` line rather than an extra `break`.

Comment: True but break is used for the same purpose. Just because there is an alternative doesn't mean break is bad. Why do you think python implements a break keyword?

Comment: So that you can have custom `break` statements in case something happens.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you mean a `for loop`. You do it like so:

```
for i in range(10):
    print i
```

This is the simplest way. You can use `xrange` rather than `range` for very long loops to help with memory management.

Also there are ways to iterate through iterable objects (like lists, arrays, strings etc.):

```
a=[1,2,3]
for something in a:
    print something
```

You could also use comprehension to make the code shorter, but that's a bit more advanced and you probably don't need it just yet. Should you so wish to learn what it's about [this](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) looks OK for a start.